# PHP Curl after execution does not return back to Ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I was integrating a PHP code to ping sitemap to google and Bing. The code executed perfectly but to be a fact if i'm initiating the request from a ajax call. It does not return back

Below is the Jquery code i'm using to make ajax call

```
$("body").on('click', 'button#sitemap_google_submit', function(event){
    toastr.info("Would require few seconds, Please wait, do not refresh Page..",
                "Submitting Sitemap to Google!",
                {   progressBar:!0,
                    showMethod:"slideDown",
                    hideMethod:"slideUp",
                    timeOut:2e3,
                    preventDuplicates: true,
                    positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"
                }
            );
    $("button#sitemap_google_submit").attr("disabled", true);
    $("button#sitemap_google_submit").html("<i class='ft-loader spinner'></i> &nbsp;Submitting to Google..");

    $.ajax({
            url: '/bypasser/modules/seoController.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {type: 'submit', console: 'google'},
        })
        .done(function(resp) {
            $("button#sitemap_google_submit").attr("disabled", false);
            $("button#sitemap_google_submit").html("<i class='fa fa-google fa-lg'></i> &nbsp;Submit to Google");
            toastr[resp.type](resp.message, 
                              resp.heading,
                    {   showMethod:"slideDown",
                        hideMethod:"slideUp",
                        preventDuplicates: true,
                        positionClass: "toast-bottom-right"
                    });
        });
    });
```

on PHP side i'm using below request

```
<?php
include("appController.php");

$reqType = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $_REQUEST['type']);

class seoController Extends appController
{
    public function submitGoogle($url)
    {
        $url = "http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=".$this->websiteBaseURL().$url;
        $returnCode = $this->myCurl($url);
        if($returnCode == 200) {
            echo json_encode(array("type" => "success",
                                    "heading" => "Success!",
                                    "message" => "Sitemap Submitted to Google!!")
                        );
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("type" => "warning",
                                    "heading" => "Warning!",
                                    "message" => "Problem occured while submitted SiteMap, try again after Sometime!"
                                )
                            );
        }
    }

    function myCurl($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , true);  // we want headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);  // we don't need body
        curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $httpCode;
    }
}

$seoController = new seoController();

if($reqType == "submit" && 
    preg_replace("/[^a-z]/", "", $_POST['console']) == "google")
        $seoController->submitGoogle("sitemap.xml");
?>
```

The JSON encodes displays perfectly in the preview panel of network tab of inspect element, but somehow it does not return the response to ajax, what is the issue?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: _For consistancy_ put `public` in front of `function myCurl($url)`

Comment: _Does method_ `$this->websiteBaseURL()` actually exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , false);  // we don't want headers
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , true);  // we want headers
```

we don't want the headers as well, as far a i understand your question, you may be looking for ping status code only!

Comment: Worked like charm :D tysm a lot!